# Installing Sitecore package from a command line

Tags: batch-file, build-automation, sitecore

Is it possible to install a Sitecore package (containing content tree changes only) from a command line via batch/power shell instead of going into Sitecore UI?
I am looking for the best way to automate our build deployments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Power Shell. Great source of information on how to use Power Shell with Sitecore can be found on Adam Najmanowicz blog ( http://blog.najmanowicz.com/category/software-development/powershell/ ).

And some information about exporting and importing packages is in his post http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2011/12/19/continuous-deployment-in-sitecore-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

There is also an experimental powershell install script avaliable at the Sitecore GitHub that also might be useful if you are doing full build deployments from scratch .. https://github.com/Sitecore/PowerShell-Script-Library

(Please feel free to fork and feedback any improvements !)